# Why catkin_make is giving an error in mavros?

Tags: simulation, ros, gazebo-simu, dronekit-python, px4

Why catkin_make is giving an error in mavros?
I am unable to build mavros by using catkin_make and i also tried catkin_make_isolated but it didn't work.
i tried reinstalling mavros but it didn't work.
I followed all the commands in PX4-autopilot website tutorial for gazebo simulation but it didn't work.
[first i tried catkin_make in catkin_ws but it didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jadCm.png)

[then i tried catkin_make_isolated in catkin_ws but it didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXSGd.png)

Comment: In the error messages in the screenshot you provided for catkin_make_isolated, it appears as though the header definitions (PROTOCOL_VERSION, for example) are throwing errors because of previous definitions. Looks like you have two versions of the source code, one in your home directory, and one in /opt. Have you previously built mavros on this system before? Or have you done a partial build?